# Properties.Settings - Multiple forms

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, application-settings, properties.settings

I have two forms:

- `MainForm`
- `SettingsForm`

As you can imagine, `MainForm` uses values such as `Properties.Settings.Default.Path` and `SettingsForm` should be able to configure such a value on runtime.

But somehow `SettingsForm: Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` takes effect just after application restart, although I'm reloading those settings in `MainForm: Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();`

I have this so far:

In `MainForm.cs`:

```
    // Handles "config button click" => display settings form
    private void configStatusLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SettingsForm form = new SettingsForm();
        form.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(form_FormClosed);
        form.Show();
    }

    // Callback triggered on Settings form closing
    void form_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
    }

    // There are another methods called after form_FormClosed is triggered, for example
    // StremWriter = new StreamWriter(  Properties.Settings.Default.Path)
```

And `SettingsForm.cs`:

```
    // Triggered on "Save button click" in Settings form, after changing values
    // Example: Properties.Settings.Default.Path = "C:\\file.txt" 
    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        Close();
    }
```

What am I missing? **How can I achieve "on demand change"?**

---

#### More on program flow

In main form, there are several buttons which will trigger function such as `ReloadLog()` which uses `Properties.Settings.Default.Path`. So at the end I'm having functions executed at this order:

```
ReloadLog(); // Triggered by the user (several times)
             // This reloads contents of log, say C:\\main.log

configStatusLabel_Click(); // User hit "configure button", there are two active forms
                           // SettingsForm is now displayed too

// At this point ReloadLog() may be called in MainForm many times
// Meanwhile in SettingsForm:
Properties.Settings.Default.Path = PathTextBox.Text;
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // User hit save button
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    Close(); // This will trigger form_FormClosed in main form
}

// Now you would expect that following line will open D:\\another.log
ReloadLog();
// But it still uses original config, however when I turn app off and on again, it works
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to call the methods that actually _use_ the settings for this "on demand change" to have any effect?

Comment: @AustinSalonen of course there are lot of methods that use those values, but I didn't see any point on pasting them, if you think it'll help I'll add all 50 of them ;)

Comment: So you do call them after changing the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void configStatusLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SettingsForm form = new SettingsForm();
    form.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(form_FormClosed);
    form.FormClosed += (s, e) => { MethodThatAppliesTheSettings(); };
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: Those settings aren't used on form close, I have "Reload log" button in main form which reloads log file (file is configurable via `SettingsForm`) and user may hit it whenever he wants.

It always uses the same path (when I hit the button) until I close and reopen application.

Comment: My guess is that it'll have something to do with [thread safe settings "synchronization"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsbase.synchronized(v=vs.80).aspx)